# java.net.ProtocolException: expected * bytes but received * #4302

Tags: android

```
@post()
@multipart
Call<FileUploadResult[]> upload File(@nonnull @part MultipartBody.Part... files);


MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file","Timesheet-" + 
new Date().getTime() + FileUtils.IMAGE_EXT,
RequestBody.create(
MediaType.parse(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName())), file));

ServiceBuilder.getService().uploadFile(body).enqueue(syncCallback);
```

I got this bug when upload an image using `MultipartBody.Part` and it throw that exception. Here is the code: java.net.ProtocolException: expected * bytes but received *

As some one who have the same issue, its wrong content-lenght between HEADER and BODY but i dont think so cause i dont modify anything when call API and its not happen all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem is when save photo,they use another thread to save image and sometime it not enough time to save the image to sdcard -> when push image to server,its not enough the size of the image -> caught that exception

Comment: well how did you fix it?

Comment: @A.easazadeh : In my case,the "save image to sd card" and "correct the image orientation..." is working on background and when user call API to upload file,The file is saved but not yet is the final file.so the length of the file (Content-Length) is difference with the file which is modified with "correct the image orientation...".And my solution is just fire some broadcast or callback bla bla to know when the modify is done or just show the dialog so user cant do action to upload image

Answer (score 0):

I got same error while uploading a .csv file to server with multipart body request. Issue was that I was getting accelerometer and gyroscope sensor readings and was saving in .csv file continuously.  When I was getting readings and tried to send file in the api it gives me exact this error. I stopped sensors saved all readings and than sent file to the Api without any error.